# System of derivatives

Tags: derivatives

System:
$$H\to  ^{\alpha I} I \to^{\beta}$$
$$\therefore \frac {dH}{dt}=-\alpha I H$$
and$$\frac {dI}{dt}=\alpha I H-\beta I$$
$$\alpha=0.01 \;and \;\beta=0.2$$
Initial conditions: $$H(0)=800 \; and \; I(0)=2$$
I would like some guidance as to how you would solve for I in terms of H$$$$
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Amzoti Yes I have been told there is a closed form for it

Comment: @Amzoti Oh wow. I didn't realise that. Thanks a lot!